# Using the implicit function theorem for a function $f(x,y,z)$ , what if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial (y,z)} $ is not a square matrix?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

I want to use the implicit function theorem for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
The set $M\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is defined by the equation
$f(x,y,z)=\text{function rule}=0$ for every $(x,y,z) \in M$.

I need to show that the equation $f(x,y,z)=0$ is locally solvable for one of the variables $x,y,z$ at every point of a set $M\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ i.e. if there exist a neighborhood $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ of $x$ and a continuous differentiable function $g: U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with $g(x)=(y,z)$ and $f(x,g(x))=0$ for every $x\in U$

The best tool I have for this is the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Definitions):

But if I calculate
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial (y,z)} =\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial (y)} (x,y,z)&,&\frac{\partial f}{\partial (z)} (x,y,z)\end{pmatrix}$$

I get a $1\times 2$-Matrix of the form , so the Matrix cannot be invertable because $\frac{\partial f}{\partial (y,z)} $ is not a square matrix.

It would only make sense to me if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial (z)}(x,y,z)=0$ for every
$(x,y,z)\in M$ but that is not the case.

**Did I misunderstand the exercise and/or the meaning of the IFT?**

$(*)$ The function $f$ is part of a homework exercise. I don't want to post the **function rule** here because my question is more general and I have some reservations about posting homework questions online.
I hope my question is still clear.

Comment: Read more carefully the sentence of the IFT. In your case, it is not $\frac{\partial f}{\partial (y,z)}$ which must be invertible but $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}.$ And it won't give you $(y,z)$ as a function of $x$ but the converse. A *surface* (in $\Bbb R^3,$ defined by $1$ equation) requires 2 parameters.

Comment: So I could show for example that $f(x,y,z)=0$  and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y,z)$ is invertible.  Then I could conclude that there exist a neighborhood $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ of $(y,z)$ and a continuous differentiable function $g: U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $x=g(y,z)$ and $f(g(y,z),y,z)=0$ for every $(y,z)\in U$?

Comment: Yes, that is it.